# Need help with definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, statistical-inference

So I have the definite integral:

$$\int_0^{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}} x^{(k/2)-1} e^{-(x+y/2)} \,dx$$

I have the answer, which is: $$(\frac{uy}{(1-u)})^{(k/2)-1} e^{-(\frac{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}+y}2)} (\frac y{{(1-u)}^2}) \,$$

but not sure where the: $$(\frac y{{(1-u)}^2})$$

is coming from. Any explanation would be much appreciated.

I've added a pic of the original problem, hope that clarifies the issue.

[image: pic link]

Comment: So you're trying to differentiate this with respect to $u$? Usually when someone gives an integral without saying more, it's to integrate it.

Comment: Link at bottom with original problem, hope it helps.

Comment: that term comes from applying the chain rule, differentiating the upper limit of integration wrt $u$

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. If possible could you tell me why we are taking a derivative inside an integral? Or just tell me if I should do this for all similar integrals, or if it is related to the specific problem I am doing?

Comment: we aren't taking a derivative inside the integral, we are doing the fundamental thrm of calc